# In tensorflow, what is the difference between a constant and a non-trainable variable?

Tags: tensorflow

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35688187/348412),

> the value of a `tf.constant()` is stored multiple times in memory.

This provides a practical answer to whether to use a tensorflow constant or non-trainable variable when you have some big tensor that should not change value.

However, it is not clear to me why both exist, and why (and under which circumstances) `tf.constant` would be replicated in memory.

Answer (score 1):

If you do `W = tf.constant(embedding, name="W")` then the value of the embedding is stored twice -- on the numpy side in `embedding` and on the TensorFlow side in `W` op. Note that `constant` values are stored in `Graph` object which is not optimized for large parallel data transfers (at least there were performance complaints before [acac487a](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/commit/acac487a) ), meanwhile `Variable` value store is optimized

Comment: So, when would it be better to use a constant?