# Create tf.constant given indices and values

Tags: python, tensorflow

I want to improve my current code in order to improve the execution performance on my GPU so I am replacing the operations that it does not support to avoid delegating them to the CPU.

One of this operations is tf.sparse_to_dense. So, is there some way to create a Tensor (constant) from its indices and values as if it were an Sparse Tensor?

I made it work with workarounds like getting the array using numpy and then creating it with `tensor = tf.constant(numpyarray)` but I was looking for an "only Tensorflow" approach.

Answer (score 0):

[`tf.constant`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/constant) currently does not support instantiation in coordinate format (indices and values) so the numpy/scipy workaround is actually not a bad one:

```
import scipy.sparse as sps

A = sps.coo_matrix((values, (indices[0,:], indices[1,:])), shape=your_shape)
tensor_A = tf.constant(A.to_dense())
```

If having a non-trainable `tf.Variable` can be an option (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41150741/in-tensorflow-what-is-the-difference-between-a-constant-and-a-non-trainable-var) for the differences with `tf.constant`), you could use `tf.sparse_to_dense`

```
tensor_A = tf.Variable( \
              tf.sparse_to_dense(indices, your_shape, values), \
              trainable=False \
           )
```

Comment: `tf.sparse_to_dense` is my current implementation, but I was trying to replace it since my GPU doesn't support it.