# Loading pre-trained word2vec to initialise embedding_lookup in the Estimator model_fn

Tags: tensorflow, word2vec, google-cloud-ml-engine

I am solving a text classification problem. I defined my classifier using the `Estimator` class with my own `model_fn`. I would like to use Google's pre-trained `word2vec` embedding as initial values and then further optimise it for the task at hand.

I saw this post: [Using a pre-trained word embedding (word2vec or Glove) in TensorFlow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35687678/using-a-pre-trained-word-embedding-word2vec-or-glove-in-tensorflow)
which explains how to go about it in 'raw' TensorFlow code. However, I would really like to use the `Estimator` class.

As an extension, I would like to then train this code on Cloud ML Engine, is there a good way of passing in the fairly large file with initial values?

Let's say we have something like:

```
def build_model_fn():
    def _model_fn(features, labels, mode, params):
        input_layer = features['feat'] #shape=[-1, params["sequence_length"]]
        #... what goes here to initialize W

        embedded = tf.nn.embedding_lookup(W, input_layer)
        ...
        return predictions

estimator = tf.contrib.learn.Estimator(
    model_fn=build_model_fn(),
    model_dir=MODEL_DIR,
    params=params)
estimator.fit(input_fn=read_data, max_steps=2500)
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Embeddings are typically large enough that the only viable approach is using them to initialize a `tf.Variable` in your graph. This will allow you to take advantage of param servers in distributed, etc.

For this (and anything else), I would recommend you use the new "core" estimator, [`tf.estimator.Estimator`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/estimator/Estimator) as this will make things much easier.

From the answer in the link you provided, and knowing that we want a variable not a constant, we can either take approach:

(2) Initialize the variable using a feed dict, or
 (3) Load the variable from a checkpoint

---

I'll cover option (3) first since it's much easier, and better:

In your `model_fn`, simply initialize a variable using the `Tensor` returned by a [`tf.contrib.framework.load_variable`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r1.0/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/framework/load_variable) call. This requires:

1. That you have a valid TF checkpoint with your embeddings
2. You know the *fully qualified* name of the embeddings variable within the checkpoint.

The code is pretty simple:

```
def model_fn(mode, features, labels, hparams):
  embeddings = tf.Variable(tf.contrib.framework.load_variable(
      'gs://my-bucket/word2vec_checkpoints/',
      'a/fully/qualified/scope/embeddings'
  ))
  ....
  return tf.estimator.EstimatorSpec(...)
```

However this approach won't work for you if your embeddings weren't produced by another TF model, hence option (2).

---

For (2), we need to use [`tf.train.Scaffold`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/train/Scaffold) which is essentially a configuration object that holds all the options for starting a `tf.Session` (which estimator intentionally hides for lots of reasons).

You may specify a `Scaffold` in the [`tf.train.EstimatorSpec`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/estimator/EstimatorSpec) you return in your `model_fn`.

We create a placeholder in our model_fn, and make it the 
initializer operation for our embedding variable, then pass an `init_feed_dict` via the `Scaffold`.  e.g.

```
def model_fn(mode, features, labels, hparams):
  embed_ph = tf.placeholder(
      shape=[hparams.vocab_size, hparams.embedding_size], 
      dtype=tf.float32)
  embeddings = tf.Variable(embed_ph)
  # Define your model
  return tf.estimator.EstimatorSpec(
      ..., # normal EstimatorSpec args
      scaffold=tf.train.Scaffold(init_feed_dict={embed_ph: my_embedding_numpy_array})
  )
```

What's happening here is the `init_feed_dict` will populate the values of the `embed_ph` placeholder at runtime, which will then allow the `embeddings.initialization_op` (assignment of the placeholder), to run.

---

Comment: Thanks, just a small thing: it should be `tf.estimator.EstimatorSpec(..., scaffold=tf.train.Scaffold(init_feed_dict={embed_ph: my_embedding_numpy_array})`

Comment: Thanks Tristan. Spaced that syntax even though I had the explanation lol.

Comment: Thanks for detailed response. I think the variable should be created with trainable=false.