# How to deal with large(>2GB) embedding lookup table in tensorflow?

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning

When I use pre-trained word vectors to do classification with LSTM, I wondered how to deal with embedding lookup table larger than 2gb in tensorflow.

To do this, I tried to make embedding lookup table like the code below,

`data = tf.nn.embedding_lookup(vector_array, input_data)`

got this value error.

`ValueError: Cannot create a tensor proto whose content is larger than 2GB`

variable vector_array on the code is numpy array, and it contains about 14 million unique tokens and 100 dimension word vectors for each word.

thank you for your helping with

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For me the accepted answer doesn't seem to work. While there is no error the results were terrible (when compared to a smaller embedding via direct initialization) and I suspect the embeddings were just the constant 0 the tf.Variable() is initialized with.

Using just a placeholder without an extra variable

```
self.Wembed = tf.placeholder(
    tf.float32, self.embeddings.shape,
    name='Wembed')
```

and then feeding the embedding on every session.run() of the graph seems to work however.

Comment: Sorry to hear it didn't work for you. When I tried it, I checked individual weights using interactive session and they were definitely not all 0s. Also, I merely quoted an answer on Stackoverflow with over 93 upvotes, which was given by an employee at Google, so not sure what went wrong - perhaps there's some typo in my code or yours. You can certainly do what you suggested and not use a variable but I don't think you'll be able to make the tensor persist that way. I save my variable so that I don't have to run this memory-consuming process in the future - I just restore saved variable.

Comment: Note that there is currently an [issue](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/17233) with Tensorflow 1.6 that slows this solution down significantly.

Answer (score 7):

You need to copy it to a tf variable. There's a great answer to this question in StackOverflow:
[Using a pre-trained word embedding (word2vec or Glove) in TensorFlow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35687678/using-a-pre-trained-word-embedding-word2vec-or-glove-in-tensorflow)

This is how I did it:

```
embedding_weights = tf.Variable(tf.constant(0.0, shape=[embedding_vocab_size, EMBEDDING_DIM]),trainable=False, name="embedding_weights") 
embedding_placeholder = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [embedding_vocab_size, EMBEDDING_DIM])
embedding_init = embedding_weights.assign(embedding_placeholder)
sess = tf.Session(config=tf.ConfigProto(log_device_placement=True)) 
sess.run(embedding_init, feed_dict={embedding_placeholder: embedding_matrix})
```

You can then use the embedding_weights variable for performing the lookup (remember to store word-index mapping)

Update: Use of the variable is not required but it allows you to save it for future use so that you don't have to re-do the whole thing again (it takes a while on my laptop when loading very large embeddings). If that's not important, you can simply use placeholders like Niklas Schnelle suggested

Comment: passing a huge matrix each run seems very expensive. Is it faster to just do the lookup outside TF and then pass the embdedded data directly?

Comment: @DankMasterDan, I tried it, but ended up with very huge vectors to store.

Answer (score 0):

Using feed_dict with large embeddings was too slow for me with TF 1.8, probably due to the issue mentioned by  Niklas Schnelle.

I ended up with the following code:

```
embeddings_ph = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, wordVectors.shape, name='wordEmbeddings_ph')
embeddings_var = tf.Variable(embeddings_ph, trainable=False, name='wordEmbeddings')
embeddings = tf.nn.embedding_lookup(embeddings_var,input_data)
.....
sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer(), feed_dict={embeddings_ph:wordVectors})
```