# How to initialize embeddings layer within Estimator API

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-estimator

I'm trying to use existing embeddings within tensorflow model, the size of embedding is greater than 2Gb and this makes my original try of doing this unsuccessful:

```
embedding_var = tf.get_variable(
        "embeddings", 
        shape=GLOVE_MATRIX.shape, 
        initializer=tf.constant_initializer(np.array(GLOVE_MATRIX))
)
```

Which gave me this error:

```
 Cannot create a tensor proto whose content is larger than 2GB.
```

I'm using AWS SageMaker, which based on the Estimator API, and the actual running of the graph in session happens behind the scene, so I'm not sure how to initialize some placeholders for embedding given that. Would be helpful if someone will be able to share the way how to do such initialization in term of EstimatorAPI.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you specify the `initializer` argument to `tf.get_variable()`, the initial value `GLOVE_MATRIX` will be stored in the graph and go over 2Gb. A good [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35688187/5098368) explains how to load embeddings in general.

---

Here is a first example where we use the initializer and the graph def is around 4Mb since it stores the `(1000, 1000)` matrix in it.

```py
size = 1000
initial_value = np.random.randn(size, size)
x = tf.get_variable("x", [size, size], initializer=tf.constant_initializer(initial_value))

sess = tf.Session()
sess.run(x.initializer)

assert np.allclose(sess.run(x), initial_value)

graph = tf.get_default_graph()
print(graph.as_graph_def().ByteSize())  # should be 4000394
```

---

Here is a better version where we don't store it:

```py
size = 1000
initial_value = np.random.randn(size, size)
x = tf.get_variable("x", [size, size])

sess = tf.Session()
sess.run(x.initializer, {x.initial_value: initial_value})

assert np.allclose(sess.run(x), initial_value)

graph = tf.get_default_graph()
print(graph.as_graph_def().ByteSize())  # should be 1203
```

---

### In Estimators

For Estimators, we don't have direct access to the Session. A way to initialize the embedding can be to use [`tf.train.Scaffold`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/train/Scaffold). You can pass it an argument `init_fn` in which you initialize the embedding variable, without saving the actual value in the graph def.

```py
def model_fn(features, labels, mode):
    size = 10
    initial_value = np.random.randn(size, size).astype(np.float32)
    x = tf.get_variable("x", [size, size])

    def init_fn(scaffold, sess):
        sess.run(x.initializer, {x.initial_value: initial_value})
    scaffold = tf.train.Scaffold(init_fn=init_fn)

    loss = ...
    train_op = ...

    return tf.estimator.EstimatorSpec(mode, loss=loss, train_op=train_op, scaffold=scaffold)
```

A good point about using the built-in Scaffold is that it will only initialize the embedding when you first call `train_input_fn`. For future calls, it will not run again `init_fn`.

Answer (score 0):

Olivier Moindrot had already given good approaches, I just add another approach I found.
In order to avoid 2GB limitation error, you should really care about the Operations you have used. The Graph in tensorflow is serializable into protobuf (an exchange format designed by google). The 2GB Error is triggered when an operation is created when checking it's attr_value exceeds 2GB，so we have to avoid packing big values into this attr_value field of operation. 
I just provide another function [tf.variable.load](https://tensorflow.google.cn/versions/r1.8/api_docs/python/tf/Variable#load), and this function will not add additional things in Graph
sample code are as follows:

```
graph2 = tf.Graph()
size = 1000
toy_embedding = np.random.randn(size, size)  # you can create your own np.ndarray

with graph2.as_default() as g2:
    emb2 = tf.Variable(initial_value=tf.ones(shape=(size,size)), name='emb2')
    sess = tf.Session()
    init_op = tf.global_variables_initializer()
    sess.run(init_op)
    emb2.load(toy_embedding, session = sess)
    out = sess.run(emb2)
    print (out)

graph2.as_graph_def().ByteSize()
```