# Obtaining sentence embedding by getting the mean of all its word embeddings in Tensorflow?

Tags: python, tensorflow

Here is my code for splitting the input Tensor with type tf.string and extracting each of its word embeddings using a pre-trained GloVe model. However, I get unwarranted errors regarding the **cond** implementation. I wonder if there is a cleaner way to obtain embeddings for all words in a **string tensor**.

```
# Take out the words
target_words = tf.string_split([target_sentence], delimiter=" ")

# Tensorflow parallel while loop variable, condition and body
i = tf.constant(0, dtype=tf.int32)
cond = lambda self, i: tf.less(x=tf.cast(i, tf.int32), y=tf.cast(tf.shape(target_words)[0], tf.int32))
sentence_mean_embedding = tf.Variable([], trainable=False)

def body(i, sentence_mean_embedding):
    sentence_mean_embedding = tf.concat(1, tf.nn.embedding_lookup(params=tf_embedding, ids=tf.gather(target_words, i)))

    return sentence_mean_embedding

embedding_sentence = tf.reduce_mean(tf.while_loop(cond, body, [i, sentence_mean_embedding]))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a cleaner way to do this with [`index_table_from_file`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/lookup/index_table_from_file) and [Dataset API](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset).

**First**, create your own `tf.Dataset` (I assume we have two sentences with some arbitary labels):

```
sentence = tf.constant(['this is first sentence', 'this is second sentence'])
labels = tf.constant([1, 0])
dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((sentence, labels))
```

**Second**, create a `vocab.txt` file that each line's number in this file maps to the same index in the `Glove` embedding. For example, if the first vocabulary in Glove is "absent" in `vocab.txt` the first line should "absent" and so on. For simplicity, assume our `vocab.txt` contains the following words:

```
first
is
test
this
second
sentence
```

Then, based on [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/lookup/index_table_from_file), define a table that its goal is to convert each word to specific id:

```
table = tf.contrib.lookup.index_table_from_file(vocabulary_file="vocab.txt", num_oov_buckets=1)
dataset = dataset.map(lambda x, y: (tf.string_split([x]).values, y))
dataset = dataset.map(lambda x, y: (tf.cast(table.lookup(x), tf.int32), y))

dataset = dataset.batch(1)
```

**Finally**, based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35687678/using-a-pre-trained-word-embedding-word2vec-or-glove-in-tensorflow), by using [`nn.embedding_lookup()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/nn/embedding_lookup) convert each sentence to embedding:

```
glove_weights = tf.get_variable('embed', shape=embedding.shape, initializer=initializer=tf.constant_initializer(embedding), trainable=False)

iterator = dataset.make_initializable_iterator()
x, y = iterator.get_next()

embedding = tf.nn.embedding_lookup(glove_weights, x)
sentence = tf.reduce_mean(embedding, axis=1)
```

---

Complete code in eager mode:

```
import tensorflow as tf

tf.enable_eager_execution()

sentence = tf.constant(['this is first sentence', 'this is second sentence'])
labels = tf.constant([1, 0])

dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((sentence, labels))
table = tf.contrib.lookup.index_table_from_file(vocabulary_file="vocab.txt", num_oov_buckets=1)
dataset = dataset.map(lambda x, y: (tf.string_split([x]).values, y))
dataset = dataset.map(lambda x, y: (tf.cast(table.lookup(x), tf.int32), y))

dataset = dataset.batch(1)

glove_weights = tf.get_variable('embed', shape=(10000, 300), initializer=tf.truncated_normal_initializer())

for x, y in dataset:
    embedding = tf.nn.embedding_lookup(glove_weights, x)
    sentence = tf.reduce_mean(embedding, axis=1)
    print(sentence.shape)
```

Comment: ids: A Tensor with type int32 or int64 containing the ids to be looked up in params.

Comment: I missed the fact that ids is a tensor of (list of) various ids. Hence I was trying to iterate through the sentence ids one by one. Passing a vectorized sentence using tf.string_split through ids would be enough.