# Convert an input string tensor to python string

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have two dictionaries below:

```
word2int = {}
int2word = {}

for i,word in enumerate(words):
    word2int[word] = i
    int2word[i] = word

def euclidean_dist(vec1, vec2):
    return np.sqrt(np.sum((vec1-vec2)**2))

def find_closest(word_index, vectors):
    min_dist = 10000 # to act like positive infinity
    min_index = -1
    query_vector = vectors[word_index]
    for index, vector in enumerate(vectors):
        if euclidean_dist(vector, query_vector) < min_dist and not np.array_equal(vector, query_vector):
            min_dist = euclidean_dist(vector, query_vector)
            min_index = index
    return min_index
```

I have an input string tensor `X`.  I would like to use `X` an index in `word2int` as shown below:

```
X = tf.placeholder(tf.string)
find_closest_word = tf.convert_to_tensor(int2word[find_closest(word2int[X], vectors)], dtype=tf.string)
```

#### Question:

How can I convert a string tensor `X` to a python string so that it can be used as index in word2int?

Answer (score 3):

> How can I convert a string tensor X to a python string so that it can
>   be used as index in word2int?

It is not possible to get string value unless calling `sess.run(string_tensor)`.

---

It is worth to mention there is a cleaner way to convert ids to words or vice-versa with [`index_table_from_file`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/lookup/index_table_from_file). [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53991008/obtaining-sentence-embedding-by-getting-the-mean-of-all-its-word-embeddings-in-t/53991510#53991510) is a an example of how you can use it.