# Initializing variables whose sizes are greater than 2GB in tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow

I recently need to initialize a large embedding matrix in tensorflow (greater than 2GB) and the size hits the 2GB limit on protocol buffer.

I searched stackoverflow for help and was able to fine this excellent [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35687678/using-a-pre-trained-word-embedding-word2vec-or-glove-in-tensorflow/35688187#35688187) explaining the use of placeholder for this kind of situation. While the placeholder solution works quite well, I found out that the following solution using tf initializer also works, but I don't understand why this solution will not be a problem to the 2GB limit.

```
import tensorflow as tf    
mb = 2 ** 20
gb = 2 ** 30
tf.reset_default_graph()
with tf.Session() as sess:
    value = tf.random_uniform([2 * gb]) # using np.random.randn will break the limit
    v = tf.get_variable("v", initializer=value, dtype=tf.float32)
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    print(sess.run(v[:10]))
    graph = tf.get_default_graph()
    print(graph.as_graph_def().ByteSize() / mb) # 0.0012083053588867188
```

Does this work because `tf.random*` initializers internally inspect the shape of the tensors to be generated and switch to a placeholder implementation accordingly? However, if we look at the graph on tensorboard, we will not see any placeholder node in the graph.

Thanks!